# SelectList in MVC incorrect syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, linq

What am I doing wrong here?

What I am trying to do is populate a list of Function Value and function Name into a jSon result that I will then use on my main page with jQuery.

The error is:

> Error 5   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

```
    public ActionResult FilterFunctionList(int departmentID = 0)
    {
        if (departmentID == 0)
        {
            return this.Json(string.Empty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        IPACS_Departments ipacs_department = db.IPACS_Department.Find(departmentID);
        SelectList ipacs_functions = ipacs_department.IPACS_Functions.Select(m => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.functionID).Trim(),
            Text = m.name
        });


        return this.Json(ipacs_functions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [constructor of `SelectList` that takes an `IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
SelectList ipacs_functions = new SelectList(
    ipacs_department.IPACS_Functions.Select(m => new SelectListItem {
        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.functionID).Trim(),
        Text = m.name
    })
,   "Value"
,   "Text"
);
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying this function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities. and points to }) second to last line.

Comment: @JamesWilson What's the type of `IPACS_Functions`?

Comment: IPACS_Functions is of type IPACS_Functions.  Which is a custom entity model.  Maybe I am going about this completely wrong.  The IPACS_Functions model has many properties.  All I need from that is a Value/Name of each IPACS_Functions returned in json format.

Comment: @JamesWilson Can you replace `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.functionID).Trim()` with `m.functionID.ToString()` then?

Comment: That is getting me closer.  It is returning a 4 deep array which is correct.  However now the Text = "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem and the value = null for all 4.

Comment: Stepping through it they are the same in VS as well.  Although when I hover over m.functionID it shows the correct id and the same for the name but when I add a watch for ipacs_functions it shows it was populated with System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem and null.

Comment: @JamesWilson Try adding two more parameters to the constructor to indicate which fields should be taken for the text and the value.

Answer (score 0):

**dasblinkenlight** is certainly correct, but I prefer to define these collections as `IEnumberable<SelectListItem>` in my ViewModel code behind to cut down on having to have those magic-stringed "Value" and "Text" parameters:

```
public int FavoriteMovieID { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MoviesToSelectFrom 
{
    get
    {
        return from x in OrderDetailsRepo.GetAllMovies()
                select new SelectListItem {
                    Text = x.Title,
                    Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                    Selected = x.id == this.FavoriteMovieID,
                };
    }
}
```

Looks a little cleaner, IMHO. And on the View side, all your helper methods simply require `IEnumberable<SelectListItem>` (which SelectList implements!), so they look the same:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FavoriteMovieID, Model.MoviesToSelectFrom)
```